# Redshift ALTER TABLE ALTER DISTSTYLE EVEN

Tags: amazon-redshift

I changed `DISTSTYLE` of my Redshift table to `KEY`:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER DISTSTYLE KEY DISTKEY column_name;
```

everything is working fine. Next, I'd like to change `DISTSTYLE` to `EVEN`. I use the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER DISTSTYLE EVEN;
```

but it fails with the following error:

```
[XX000] ERROR: Unsupported ALTER TABLE ALTER DISTEVEN
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm going to assume that there isn't a vacuum running - this can cause this alter to fail

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried `VACUUM FULL` but unfortunately it didn't help